# How to download PDF file using HtmlUnit

Tags: javascript

I am using htmlunit to scrape a website, I however need to click a link that downloads a pdf file. How do i go about it? The link has its href as a javascript doc

Thanks.

Comment: I have tried two major things. I tried to use the click option of HtmlUnit on anchors and I have also tried the "execute javascript" option of HtmlUnit. The two options doesn't work, however I realised yesterday that HtmlUnit breaks down when there is an error in one of the page's javascript code, hence it won't be able to execute subsequent javascript code in the page. So now I am looking for a robust scrapper that can tolerate some degree of errors in a html page and javascript codes.

Answer (score 0):

First you determine somehow the selector of the link, let's suppose you are storing it in a `selector` variable.

Then call

```
$(selector).click();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have however done something close to that, it just skips the click option and proceed to the next action. I have however realised that the website has some errors in some of its javascipt code, hence HtmlUnit breaks down when it encounters that and can not execute any javascript function.

Comment: Well, then it looks like my answer should be correct in general, but not for your case. I believe you should describe your case a little bit more in an answer and... answer your own question, which is actually encouraged by this website.

Comment: I have not found solution to the problem, I only know what is causing the problem now. That's why I can't provide an answer yet.Thanks.